# Retain query string value in seachbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to know how we can retain the query string value from url in our seachbox when that value is searched for and new page loads using jquery

Comment: welcome to SO, please provide more details, if possible code example replicating the issue or a working example in JSfiddle.

Comment: localstorage / pass in the url / pass in the form / return with the next page that loads, eg pagemodel depending on (undisclosed) back end.

Comment: @NarenMurali While I agree with your comment, I don't think we should ask for JSFiddle, but instead ask for the use of the snippet tool that SO provides, that way we'll always have the code/snippet here.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Ok my bad, will do the same in future :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html) might be what you want:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

For example the search query string in URL:

```
https://searcher.com?search=searchsomething
```

And you have a searchbox (textbox):

```
<input type="text" id="searchbox" value="">
```

Then you need:

```
document.getElementById("searchbox").value = getUrlVars()["search"]
```

The expected result in the searchbox will be:

```
<input type="text" id="searchbox" value="searchsomething">
```